# Ideas for Securing AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, security, encryption

Question:  Best practices for sending sensitive data (which must eventually be decrypted) via AJAX to a PHP file.

Example Case: WordPress plugin that allows a person to enter their API token for accessing a particular webservice.  The token is saved to the DB, and thenceforth only used by server-side files to the API's HTTPS endpoints.

Considerations:

1. This is a plugin people will deploy on their websites, so I have no way of knowing if they will have SSL / HTTPS.
2. The token must be en/decrypted (as opposed to hashed) and saved on their server so that the server-side files can use it to make API calls.
3. The service in question doesn't offer a way to do this server-side.  Their OAuth tokens expire after 30 days, forcing users re-auth every 30 days would make using this plugin a real headache.
4. I'd like to be mindful about sending these tokens around the internet in plain text, although it's a bit of a crapshoot without SSL, and in all honesty not the most sensitive data out there, I'd like to do what I can here.

I've read around, and here is what I am thinking:

1. API token is input into a form field in the WP admin, encrypted using an encryption library, then sent via AJAX to a PHP file hosted on the same server (ie: a part of the plugin), along with a session nonce.
2. Server receives key, decrypts, then makes a test connection to the API (API endpoint uses SSL).  Successes return OK message, failures return a NOT OK message and are logged.

Are there better solutions to consider here?

Comment: I'm actually quite surprised there aren't more options for situations such as these.  To share my progress, I am looking at [jCryption](http://www.jcryption.org) -- but I may run into issues as appears to require the openssl php extension, and I won't know if that's available on whatever server an end user is on.  There is [NoSSL](http://www.nossl.net), but the license appears to be restricted to non-commercial use.

If neither option works, I may try to handroll a public/private solution.  Each install would be create a unique pair to en/decrypt whatever is sent via ajax.

Comment: The problem with JavaScript is that if the page itself is not protected in any way, then securing AJAX is a moot point. Use TLS for the site, solution space empty; nothing to trust.